Tomcat 9 digest clear text password
I'm having an issue with clear text password Tomcat9 on Windows, which is JDBC connection Tomcat9 connect to DB. I tried to digest the password with digest.bat and change the server.xml
or add Realm, but both ways not work.
Here is my server.xml code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Server port="8105" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />

  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />

  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
    <Resource auth="Container"      name="jdbc/BALart"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory"
        maxTotal="8"
        username="balart_int"
        password="PT7mo39UaKgT"
        driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
        url="jdbc:sqlserver://sql:1114;databaseName=BALALL;instance=F_CIAS;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false"
        maxIdle="8"
    />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <Service name="Catalina">

    <Connector port="8180" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               proxyPort="443"
               scheme="https"
               address="127.0.0.1"
               redirectPort="8443"
               maxParameterCount="1000"
               relaxedQueryChars="'^{}[]|&quot;" />

    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>


Hide the clear text password
